# Virtual CloneDrive hijacking USB drives

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, windows-10

I installed Virtual CloneDrive in Windows 7. With Windows 10's ability to natively mount ISOs, I had no need for it. I un-installed it using Revo.

Revo said a file couldn't be deleted, but would be deleted at next reboot.
I rebooted, and I *think* the file was deleted.

Anyway, for the question:

Whenever I plug a USB drive in, It either has the Virtual Clone Drive icon, or a blank page icon like this one:

[image]

Sometimes, I will randomly get the Virtual CloneDrive drives showing up in this PC. The USB drives also mount slower. I have not been able to test with an external hard drive. Internal drives show up fine.

How do I reset the icons, and more importantly, how do I scrap every last bit of Virtual CloneDrive from my system.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First step is to find the drivers and not load them to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Where would I find those?

Comment: Use a program like Autoruns

Answer (score 0):

On my a Windows 10 computer I had installed Virtual CloneDrive. When I no longer needed it I uninstalled it. Then after installing the Windows 10 2004 update, my external USB enclosure showed the hard drive as a Virtual CloneDrive. My solution was to reinstall Virtual CloneDrive and then uninstall it again.

Start button → ElaborateBytes → Uninstall Virtual CloneDrive.